# Laravel ShouldQueue results in history issues

Tags: laravel

My EncodeVideo.php

```
class EncodeVideo implements ShouldQueue
```

The  handle() function

```
public function handle()
{
        Log::debug('handle');
```

gives random history versions of my Log::debug function
Sometimes it output log::debug content I changed 30 minutes ago

I tried to clear artisan cache and artisan clear queue with no success

Comment: I do not fully understand what the issue is, but I think I still know what is happening, you are changing the code and the job is not really reflecting that? did you stop and start the queue workers? Cache has nothing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question was not clear to me
If I understood correctly, you could solve your problem by running the following commands
(I noticed that you cleared the cache, but try again, I hope it helps)

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan event:clear
```

If it doesn't work, try this

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan event:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```